# Divide and find maximum value in for loop: Python

Tags: python

I have the following loop:

```
for key, value in sentiment_dict.items():
    print ("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

Which prints out

```
Bullish: 9
Bearish: 1
```

I would like to divide the smaller value by the bigger value (1/9), in this case "Bullish" is bigger but it could be the other way around. After that I want to print out

```
"There is a %s probability that the stock is %s" % (percentage, text with smaller n)
#In this case it would be
"There is a .1111 probability that the stock is Bearish"
```

What functions or methods should I use in this scenario??

EDIT: Here is the rest of the code in case it helps

```
import requests
link= 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/'+input+'.json'
a=requests.get(link)
a=a.json()

from collections import Counter
sentiment_dict = Counter()
for message in a['messages']:
    if 'entities' in message:
        if 'sentiment' in message['entities']:
            sentiment = message['entities']['sentiment']
            if sentiment is not None:
               sentiment = sentiment['basic']
               sentiment_dict[sentiment] += 1
for key, value in sentiment_dict.items():
print ("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
min_value = min(sentiment_dict.values())
max_value = max(sentiment_dict.values())
min_key = {value:key for (key, value) in sentiment_dict.items()}[min_value]

print("There is a %s probability that the stock is %s" % (min_value/max_value, min_key))
```

The third line will reverse the dictionary to get the key that corresponds with the minimum value.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to divide the smaller value by the bigger value

`min()` and `max()` are [built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

```
min(a,b) / max(a,b)
```

Comment: I tried `print(min(value,key)/max(value,key))` and got `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()`

Comment: that's because it should be `min(value1, value2)/max(value1, value2)`